# Cocoapods + Command Line Tool - dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Versions/A/Realm

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode-command-line-tools

I created a Command Line Tool project in Xcode 8.2.1, then I ran `pod init` and added `RealmSwift` to it. After `pod install`, I opened the `.xcworkspace` file.

The project compiles fine, but at runtime I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Versions/A/Realm
Referenced from: /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-eqotetgxsfjvxjfevywenvddnfdm/Build/Products/Debug/myproject
Reason: image not found
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

How can I use cocoapods here?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3707

In other words cocoa pods don't work with "Command Line Tool" projects.

Answer (score 2):

in podfile, comment the `use_frameworks!` line

credit [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580003683).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your project setting under Link Binary with Libraries as 'Optional' not as 'Required' for Pod_PROJECT-NAME.framework

[image]

Comment: I did, did not help unfortunately.